# What's wrong with this protobuffer decode?

Tags: javascript, node.js, protocol-buffers

I'm decoding some buffers with Google protobuffer. I'm using the excellent @decodeIO [ProtoBuf.js](https://github.com/dcodeIO/ProtoBuf.js) module.

When I try to decode this Buffer:

```
<Buffer 0a 0b 47 57 5f 2d 31 38 5f 39 39 32 39>
```

From this message:

```
message PaymentResponseElement {
  optional int64  pnPaymentId       = 1;
  optional string messageCode       = 2; //won't use pb enum here
  optional int64  balanceAfterTransaction   = 3;
  optional int32  version           = 4;
}
```

I get this error:

```
Error: Illegal wire type for field Message.Field .core.comm.PaymentResponseElement.messageCode: 2 (0 expected)
    at ProtoBuf.Reflect.Field.decode (/home/joojo/node_modules/protobufjs/ProtoBuf.js:2095:27)
    at ProtoBuf.Reflect.Message.decode (/home/joojo/node_modules/protobufjs/ProtoBuf.js:1748:51)
    at ProtoBuf.Reflect.Field.decode (/home/joojo/node_modules/protobufjs/ProtoBuf.js:2196:46)
    at ProtoBuf.Reflect.Message.decode (/home/joojo/node_modules/protobufjs/ProtoBuf.js:1746:51)
    at Function.Message.decode (/home/joojo/node_modules/protobufjs/ProtoBuf.js:1630:41)
    at decode (/home/joojo/public_html/api/control/protoBuffer.js:94:52)
    at Object.module.exports.decode (/home/joojo/public_html/cageapi/control/protoBuffer.js:110:10)
    at decode (/home/joojo/public_html/api/control/messageStructurer.js:82:33)
    at Object.module.exports.decode (/home/joojo/public_html/api/control/messageStructurer.js:94:10
    at CleartextStream.month (/home/joojo/public_html/api/connectionHandler.js:83:32)
```

Don't know whats going on, and it's happened a few times. How to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have to agree with the implementation. That data is only 1 field - field number 1, length-prefixed (could be a string, binary, or a sub-message **edit** or packed-array); if we speculatively interpret it as a string (which is always UTF-8 in protouf), it comes out as `"GW_-18_9929"`, which looks sane.

However, your message declared field 1 as `int64`. The string/length-prefix wire-type (wire-type 2) is not valid for int64 - in fact, the only valid wire-type for that is 64-bit (wire-type 1).

So: your data is *valid*, but it doesn't match the schema you are claiming.

To unscramble:

- 0a is binary 1010 - the last three bits (010) is the wire-type, 2 = length delimited; the remaining 1 is the field-number: 1
- 0b is decimal 11, the length of the field that follows
- 47 57 5f 2d 31 38 5f 39 39 32 39 is the payload, UTF-8 for `"GW_-18_9929"`

Comment: Wow! How nice... Thank you man . Iv tried to decode with protoc --decode_raw.. but no succes...